# Autofocus setting in a jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, attributes, autofocus

```
attr({ type: 'text', id: input_id,placeholder: placeholder})
```

How can is set autofocus attribute like other attributes in the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the autofocus attribute simply use: `{autofocus: true}`

So your whole call would be:

```
$jqEl.attr({
    type: 'text', 
    id: input_id,
    placeholder: placeholder, 
    autofocus: true
});
```

In case you wish to add `focus` after a specific event / rendering / timer etc. use the `$.fn.focus()` function like

```
$jqEl.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rather use `.focus()` after setting the attributes

```
 attr({ type: 'text', id: input_id,placeholder: placeholder}).focus()
```